# Mysql ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql

I have the following existing table in a mysql database:

```
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| f1                  | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| field2              | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| field3              | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field4              | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field6              | varchar(64)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field7              | varchar(16)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field8              | varchar(32)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field9              | varchar(128)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field10             | varchar(128)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field11             | varchar(128)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field12             | varchar(64)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field13             | varchar(32)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field14             | varchar(32)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field15             | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| field16             | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field17             | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field18             | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| field19             | varchar(64)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field20             | varchar(64)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field21             | varchar(16)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field22             | varchar(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field23             | varchar(1000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field24             | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| field25             | int(11)       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| field26             | decimal(19,2) | YES  |     | 0.00    |                |
| field27             | decimal(19,2) | YES  |     | 0.00    |                |
| field28             | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| field29             | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| field30             | varchar(128)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field31             | varchar(128)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field32             | varchar(16)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field33             | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field34             | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field35             | varchar(128)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field36             | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| field37             | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I try the following statement to add another row and I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Here are the ways I've tried to insert the row into the table:

```
insert into table (Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra) VALUES ("contract_expiration", "date", "YES", "", "NULL", "");

insert into table VALUES ('contract_expiration','date','YES','','NULL','');
```

Both return the same error.  There are no triggers on the table, I'm not sure what's going on.

Any suggestions?  I'm relatively new to mysql administration, I know a bit but this has me stumped and searches for solutions have turned up nothing.

Any help that could be provided would be MUCH appreciated!

Comment: You realize that the table layout seems to have nothing to do with the queries you have posted.  The columns in the `insert` are not in the list.

Answer (score 4):

`NULL` is not a valid field name in:

```
insert into `table`(Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra) 
    VALUES ("contract_expiration", "date", "YES", "", "NULL", "");
```

And `Key` and `default` are  reserved words.  Try this:

```
insert into `table`(Field, `Type`, `Null`, `Key`, `Default`, Extra) 
    VALUES ("contract_expiration", "date", "YES", "", "NULL", "");
```

Comment: +1 but anyway, @user3311240 you shouldn't use reserved words for field names

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that and it gave me the following:                insert into table (Field, `Type`, `Null`, `Key`, `Default`, Extra) VALUES ("contract_expiration", "date", "YES", "", "NULL", "");
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table (Field, `Type`, `Null`, `Key`, `Default`, Extra) VALUES ("contract_expirat' at line 1

Comment: Scratch that.  I had an error... I fixed it and now I'm getting the following:  ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Field' in 'field list'

Comment: @user3311240 . . . *I* don't know what field you want to put in.  *You* should know that.  What field do you want to put `contract_expiration` in?

Comment: I'm trying to get contract_expiration into the Column named Field

Comment: @Brandon . . . "Field" is not a reserved word, so if it is in your table, then it should be fine.  However, `table` is.  So that should be quoted as well.

Comment: Any other suggestions on this folks I made another run at this based on the suggestions above and I still get the errors and the row won't insert.

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql> desc classroom;
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| clId    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| clFName | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| clSName | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| clCapc  | int(3)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from classroom;
+------+------------+---------+--------+
| clId | clFName    | clSName | clCapc |
+------+------------+---------+--------+
|    1 | Classroom1 | cl1     |    100 |
|    2 | 2          | 2       |      2 |
|    3 | 3f         | 3s      |      3 |
|    4 | 3f         | 3s      |      3 |
|    5 | class4     | class4  |    100 |
+------+------------+---------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

> I also have same error

```
mysql> insert into classroom values('Gudadhe', 'Akash', 20);
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

> This error can be solved by specifying column names before inserting directly as follows

**By writing classroom(clFName, clSName, clCapc) we are specifying columns into which we want to insert values**

```
mysql> insert into classroom(clFName, clSName, clCapc) values('Gudadhe', 'Akash', 20);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar case, where I took the table definition from a dev server and the data from a live server, and it turned out that they were actually not quite the same.

The way I found out the difference was (there are probably smarter ways to do it, but this is how I did it):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable;
```

I ran this on all 3 cases (live database, dev database, and new database I created using `CREATE TABLE xxx like xxx`).

Then I simply compared the 3 and found that the live and dev had a different set of columns, so I simply ran

```
 ALTER TABLE xxx DROP yyy;
```

until the new table was the same as the table the dump was from; then I could import data.

Comment: thanks for fixing my horrible language / grammar :-)